# Android GoogleMap -.scrollby does not work properly

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am relatively new to Android (using Eclipse) and I am trying to play around with an application that uses a googlemap. I have the map working in my mobile app and have placed a marker with a title at the location.

My problem is that I only have a small area for the map to show, which when the location is centered, kinda cuts the title off some. I just want to scroll (pan) the map a tiny bit to allow for the title to be seen clearly and a bit more centered. But I cannot seem to get this to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Single extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single); 
}

 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

 private void setUpMap() {

     LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
     CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 10);
     mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);

     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude)).title("This is a test title").showInfoWindow();

 } }
```

The above code works fine but gives me the following map:

http://www.webonepro.com/2.png

Note that the title is nearly cut off a bit. What I really want to do is pan/scroll the map a tiny bit to get the following:

http://www.webonepro.com/1.png

If I try to add in the following code, it moves the map to a default area that no longer shows the marker, rather Africa I believe:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0, 10));
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Shouldn't I be able to adjust the map up or down a little?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

When you call `animateCamera` one after another, only the last will take any effect.

You can use `moveCamera` for the first camera update call (or even for both).

Another approach would be to use `Projection` to convert to `Point`, add some offset to `y` and convert back to `LatLng`.

Comment: I went ahead and changed both calls to _moveCamera_. And while the map  no longer centers to default, it still does not actually scroll the map whatsoever. I even tried increasing the pixel amount of the Y value in scrollby to a much larger number (i.e. 1000, 9999).

What would be the syntax for doing this the _Projection_ way? Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Tom So it still looks like on http://www.webonepro.com/2.png when having two `moveCamera`s? Is the first call to `yourLocation` and second with `scrollBy`? Try changing `scrollBy` to `animateCamera` in that case.

Comment: Yes @MaciejGórski, it is still like http://www.webonepro.com/2.png. Tried changing 'scrollby' to 'animateCamera', but no effect either. This is what I have now and it still doesn't work:


`LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
   CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 10);
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("This is a test.")).showInfoWindow();
   mMap.moveCamera(yourLocation);
   mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0, 100));`

Comment: One thing that I notice that is weird, if I add a button and then place the code `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0, 100));` in it, when I press the button, the map then scrolls correctly. But why doesn't it work in my normal code and what should I do to fix it?